# Unable to open BCP host data-file error

Tags: sql-server, bcp

Having problem using BCP via xp_cmdshell.

I exported the table data to a file as .dat but when I try to import the file to a new table, I am getting the below error. The SQL Server service and the account that I am using has full access on that drive. I am not sure why I am still having issues.

> Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]  Unable to open BCP
>   host data-file.

Here are the scripts that I am running.

```
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'BCP database.dbo.tabel OUT d:\tabledata.dat -T -c' 
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'BCP database.dbo.tabelnew IN d:\tabledata.dat -T -c'
```

Comment: Have you tried executing these commands directly from the command line instead of using `xp_cmdshell`?

Comment: In my experience, BCP generally requires that the file be local to the destination server.  Is that the case?

Comment: Try `exec master..xp_cmdshell 'BCP database.dbo.tabel OUT d:\somefolder\tabledata.dat -T -c'. That should work. Note **somefolder**.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same - somehow a windows or SQL Server update changed something and a previously successful build started failing.
In my case it was access permissions to the folder containing the dat files that was failing.
I could run the bcp from the command line and it worked but it failed from SQL Server.
The SQL Service needs access to the folder, basically.
To test this, try running

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'DIR <your-dat-folder>'
```

and if that fails check your access permissions (and grant as needed).